# Issue with adding line breaks in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, line-breaks

I have a TextView that has maxLines of 10 and singleLine is set to false.

When I do something like

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.print);
text.setText("first line\n"+"second line\n"+"third line");
```

The line breaks in the TextView work without a problem.

first line

second line

third line

However, when I do this:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String receiveString = "";
while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
     ret = ret + receiveString + "\n";
}
view.setText(ret);
```

I get something like: first linesecond linethird line

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is `ret` of type `String`?

Comment: Yes sorry, return is String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this simple code--

```
private void check() {
    SigmaLog.d("first line\n" + "second line");
    String receiveString = "";
    String newString = "first line";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 2) {
        receiveString += newString + "\n";
        newString = "second line";
        i++;
    }
    SigmaLog.d(receiveString);
}
```

this code outputs the second string next line to first one.
This is same as your code.

Actually **bufferedReader.readLine()** outputs the string whatever it gets at one line till it reach to the line breaker like \n etc.
I think your loop runs only one time whatever it have in one line it delivers to you and exit from loop so the next execution is not there and no more string so how could it go to the next line.
Apply logs to check the proper values for string on every loop execution.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize I was not adding a new line when I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make: `StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();`.

2) Append to it the messages that you want:
      `ret.append(receiveString).append("\n");`

3) Set the text:
      `view.setText(ret.toString());`